# Python - How do you add \ and | to str.contains()

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

I am cleaning up a column in a pandas dataframe getting rid of garbage usernames that contain certain characters.  Here is the example:

```
d = {'username': ["11111", "222!22", "21212!", "85511$", "8552$", "115522@@"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    username
0   11111
1   222!22
2   21212!
3   85511$
4   8552$
5   115522@@
....
```

I am using the following and it is working as expected:

```
df[~df['username'].str.contains('~|`|!|@|#|\$|%|\^|&|\*|\(|\)|-|_|\+|=|{|\[|}|]|:|;|"|\'|<|,|>|\.|/|\?')]
```

But I would like to add two more characters:

`\` and `|`

When I try to add these like `\\` for `\` and `\|` for `|` but I receive errors. How should I go about this?

Comment: Try ``\\\\`` and ``\\|`` or  raw string as ``r'~|`|!|@|#|\$|%_and_so_on'`` (<- ``r`` before opening quotations mark).

Comment: This works. @Psytho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `r` in front of the string so Python will interpret your string as raw:

```
df[~df['username'].str.contains(r'~|`|!|@|#|\$|%|\^|&|\*|\(|\)|-|_|\+|=|{|\[|}|]|:|;|"|\'|<|,|>|\.|/|\?')]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Thank you @Marjan Moderc

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid manually specifying `|` conditions via [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
import re

chars = """~`!@#$%^&*()-_+={[}]:;"'<,>./?\|"""
regex_search = '|'.join(map(re.escape, chars))

res = df[~df['username'].str.contains(regex_search)]
```

This use case is specifically mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), which also advise: as of Python 3.7, only characters that can have special meaning in a regular expression are escaped.

Comment: I like this a lot @jpp